# AngularJS - How to generate random value for each ng-repeat iteration

Tags: angularjs, random

I am trying to create random span sized divs(.childBox) of twitter bootstrap using AngularJS.

```
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="motherBox" ng-repeat="n in news">
      <div class="childBox" class="col-md-{{boxSpan}} box">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="{{holderLink}}" height="200px" alt="100x100">
          <p class="tBlock"> {{n.title}} </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
  $http.get('news/abc.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.news = data;
  });
  $scope.holderSize = 150;
  $scope.holderLink = 'http://placehold.it/'+$scope.holderSize+'x'+$scope.holderSize;
  $scope.boxSpan = getRandomSpan();

  function getRandomSpan(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  };
}])
```

I want to create different integer value for boxSpan for each .childBox div but all .childBox have same boxSpan value. Although everytime i refresh page boxSpan creates random value.

How can i generate different/random value for each ng-repeat iteration?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just call add `getRandomSpan()` function to your scope and call it in your template:

```
$scope.getRandomSpan = function(){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
}

<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <div class="motherBox" ng-repeat="n in news">
    <div class="childBox" class="col-md-{{getRandomSpan()}} box">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{holderLink}}" height="200px" alt="100x100">
        <p class="tBlock"> {{n.title}} </p>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will cause digest overflow, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it causes it in my case.

Comment: To prevent digest overflow: you can use `ng-init='rand = getRandomSpan()'` and in class: `class="col-md-{{rand}} box"`

Answer (score 21):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, since you're likely to reuse this function, you can turn it into a filter for convenience:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('randomize', function() {
  return function(input, scope) {
    if (input!=null && input!=undefined && input > 1) {
      return Math.floor((Math.random()*input)+1);
    }  
  }
});
```

Then, you can define the max and use it anywhere on your app:

```
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="motherBox" ng-repeat="n in news">
      <div class="childBox" class="col-md-{{6 | randomize}} box">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="{{holderLink}}" height="200px" alt="100x100">
          <p class="tBlock"> {{n.title}} </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Improvisation of the accepted answer to prevent digest overflow:

```
var rand = 1;
$scope.initRand = function(){
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)
}

$scope.getRandomSpan = function(){
  return rand;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <div class="motherBox" ng-repeat="n in news">
    <div class="childBox" ng-init="initRand()" class="col-md-{{getRandomSpan()}} box">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{holderLink}}" height="200px" alt="100x100">
        <p class="tBlock"> {{n.title}} </p>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to use function from scope - again will be digest overflow. Just set new val: `ng-init='rand = initRand()'` and in class: class="col-md-{{rand}} box"