# how to push random value out of angularJS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a use case for having angular return a random value into the outer container of the route for the purposes of forcing cache invalidation when selecting a new route.

HTML:

```
<a ng-repeat="dx in rssFeeds" href="#/view/{{dx.name}}/{{rnd()}}">
  <img src='{{dx.icon}}'/>{{dx.name}}
</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.rnd = function () {
  return Math.random();
};
```

With the way that Angular works this will cause angular to explode with a exception when it decides that the view will never stabilize on a set of values.

There is a similar question here: [AngularJS - How to generate random value for each ng-repeat iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737594/angularjs-how-to-generate-random-value-for-each-ng-repeat-iteration)

And even though the accepted answer is complete rubbish, the second most voted answer looks like it would take me 90% of the way.

Comment: angular will call rnd during every digest cycle. Generate the number with ng-init.

Comment: @Jacob that didn't work due to the way the view is structured it dosn't get refreshed when the link is clicked. Although it turns out that I can regenerate the random number on the ng-click event and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a ng-repeat="item in array" href="#/view/{{item}}/{{rnd}}" ng-init="rnd = rnd()">
    {{item}}
  </a>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  $scope.rnd = function() {
    return Math.random();
  };
}
```

Here is [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL258jhy/)

If you want to prevent template caching you can do

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work with my use case. Since the main menu is outside of the ng-view it does not refresh with a new ng-init() when it other parts of the app refresh. After some more playing around it turns out the random number can be generated in a ng-click event.

Comment: im using the default router which comes with angular. Its a little bit of a square-peg/round hole problem.